# python: composition of `int` and `float`

Tags: python, floating-point, python-3.x

As part of some other calculations, I noticed that I sometimes apply `float()` and then `int()` function to an integer input. Is it safe to assume that:

```
int(float(x)) == x
```

if x is integer?

Why? (Or why not?) And is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All numbers of the form `significant_digits * (2 ** exponent)` have an exact representation as a floating point number, as long as you have enough bits to represent `significant_digits` and `exponent`.  Most platforms use IEEE 754 double representation, and Python uses the platform's double.  IEEE 754 doubles have 11 bits for `exponent` and 52 bits for `significant digits`.  As long as your numbers fit these bounds they will come out as expected.

See [Python's docs on floating point representation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and Wikipedia's article on [floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Comment: I guess the direct answer to my question is a simple 'no' (with an example); but I do find this additional information useful for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 8):

If `x` needs more precision than provided by double-precision floating point numbers then the comparison will fail.

```
>>> int(float(10**23))
99999999999999991611392L
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> x = 10**300
>>> int(float(x)) == x
False
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why? (Or why not?) And is it documented anywhere?

One of the definitive guides that every programmer should know well:

[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: What does that have to do with integers?

Comment: The question is about `int` and `float` types. `Float()` involves floating point, right? From Python Docs: `float() Convert a string or a number to floating point.`

Comment: But he isn't really doing any math with it.  And he specifically mentions that the input is already an integer.

Comment: As demonstrated in the other answers, such as `int(float(10**300))` it does matter. What do you think happens to the interim result once you apply `float()` to something?

Comment: Whenever I see that link by anyone, it's usually in the context of doing floating point arithmetic, not usually to point out the precision of the values.  Sorry for the confusion.  :)

Comment: Jeff: If the exact representation of `x` is slightly below the integer's original value, then it will get rounded down on the int() cast.